# Style jQuery UIDatePicker Plugin

Tags: jquery, html, uidatepicker

How is it possible to style the uidatepicker like in this example:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's theming.  Try: [http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/](http://jQuery%27s%20ThemeRoller).  If you're wanting to get into the guts of the CSS, use Firefox with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).  Inspect elements and tweak the CSS file that you used for the UI.